# I am trying to do a grade array with random #'s and converting to letter grades

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
 */
public static double ranNumber(double [] gradeArray) {
    double rN = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gradeArray.length; i++) {
        rN = 55 + Math.random() * (100 - 55) + 1;    //this section is to generate a # between 55-100. 
     }

    return rN;
}

  /**
 *
 * @param input
 * 
 */
public static void outputArray(double [] input) {  // this is where I want the random # to go and to later convert to letter grade. 

    for (int count = 1; count <= input.length; count++) {
        System.out.printf("Grade %d: %.2f is a  ", count+1 , input[count]);
    }
}
```

Ok, so I only posted these 2 methods, because what I am wanting to try to do is get the random number into the outputArray so that I can turn the double into a letter grade. My output should be something like, "Grade 1: 93.23 is a A-".

Comment: Where's your attempts at a method that returns a letter grade?

Comment: Or where do you call `ranNumber`? Why will it generate `gradeArray.length` -  many numbers, but only return one value?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want to generate an array of random grades. Your original function doesn't need to pass in an array parameter, it should return one.

```
public static double[] ranNumber(int len) {
    double[] rN = new double[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rN[i] = 55 + Math.random() * (100 - 55) + 1;    //this section is to generate a # between 55-100. 
     }

    return rN;
}
```

Then, call that method in `outputArray` and loop over it. Or pass it as the parameter from `main`

Warning... `int count = 1; count <= input.length`... `input[count]` will throw an exception